# Are reports and Dashboard packagable

Tags: community, reporting, metadata-api, package, dashboard

I have reports and dashboards for communities, which I am intending to package. are they package?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Reports and Dashboards are packageable. You can find details on the packageability of any metadata type in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage).

Comment: Thank you so much David

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this great resource. One question, so in the column 'Managed Packaging' where we have Checks, are the ones which are packagable ? and those which are not upgrable will need/required to have metaAPI to be created.

Comment: Managed Packaging = packageable in 2GP. Classic Packaging = packageable in 1GP.